# MVC Html Helper not being interpretend

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying out custom HTML Helpers in MVC 5, but they are not being interpreted in the browser. they come out as strings.

HTML Helper class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static string ImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string imgSrc, string altText)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

        builder.GenerateId(id);

        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imgSrc);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);

        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }
}
```

HTML View

```
@Html.ImageLink("objStatus", "/images/circle-205-i.png", "status")
```

Browser display:

```
string "<img alt="status" id="objStatus" src="/images/circle-205-i.png" />"
```

F12 presents it as a string not interpreted as HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper is returning a string which MVC Razor will encode as HTML. The correct way is to return an MvcHtmlString like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string imgSrc, string altText)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("img");

    builder.GenerateId(id);

    builder.MergeAttribute("src", imgSrc);
    builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);

    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

An alternative is to use `Html.Raw` in your view, but you would have to do that everywhere. I only mention this here as it is possible to do and the above is the preferred solution.

Comment: Thank you @DavidG was resigned to returning to this tomorrow. Resolved.